# Rearrange data by matching columns

Tags: r

I am having issue with rearranging some data.

The original data is:

```
structure(list(id = 1:3, artery.1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), artery.2 = structure(c(1L, NA, 2L), .Label = c("b", 
"c"), class = "factor"), artery.3 = structure(c(1L, NA, 2L), .Label = c("c", 
"d"), class = "factor"), artery.4 = structure(c(NA, NA, 1L), .Label = "e", class = "factor"), artery.5 = structure(c(NA, NA, 1L), .Label = "f", class = "factor"), 
diameter.1 = c(3L, 2L, 1L), diameter.2 = c(2L, NA, 2L), diameter.3 = c(3L, 
NA, 3L), diameter.4 = c(NA, NA, 4L), diameter.5 = c(NA, NA, 
5L)), .Names = c("id", "artery.1", "artery.2", "artery.3", 
"artery.4", "artery.5", "diameter.1", "diameter.2", "diameter.3", 
"diameter.4", "diameter.5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

#   id artery.1 artery.2 artery.3 artery.4 artery.5 diameter.1 diameter.2 diameter.3 diameter.4 diameter.5
# 1  1        a        b        c     <NA>     <NA>          3          2          3         NA         NA
# 2  2        a     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>          2         NA         NA         NA         NA
# 3  3        b        c        d        e        f          1          2          3          4          5
```

I would like to get to this:

```
structure(list(id = 1:3, a = c(3L, 2L, NA), b = c(2L, NA, 1L), 
c = c(3L, NA, 2L), d = c(NA, NA, 3L), e = c(NA, NA, 4L), 
f = c(NA, NA, 5L)), .Names = c("id", "a", "b", "c", "d", 
"e", "f"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

#   id  a  b  c  d  e  f
# 1  1  3  2  3 NA NA NA
# 2  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA
# 3  3 NA  1  2  3  4  5
```

Basically, `a` to `f` represents arteries and the numerical values represent the corresponding diameter. Each row represents a patient.

Is there a neat way to sort this dataframe out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern **tidyr** makes the solution even more succinct via the `pivot_` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_pattern = '(artery|diameter)\\.(\\d+)', names_to = c('.value', NA)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(artery)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = artery, values_from = diameter)

     id     a     b     c     d     e     f
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     3     2     3    NA    NA    NA
2     2     2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3     3    NA     1     2     3     4     5
```

Here is the older solution, which uses the deprecated `gather` and `spread` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

new.df <- gather(df, variable, value, artery.1:diameter.5) %>% 
    separate(variable, c('variable', 'num')) %>% 
    spread(variable, value) %>% 
    subset(!is.na(artery)) %>%
    mutate(diameter = as.numeric(diameter)) %>% 
    select(-num) %>% 
    spread(artery, diameter)
```

Output:

```
  id  a  b  c  d  e  f
1  1  3  2  3 NA NA NA
2  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA
3  3 NA  1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: NB that `subset` is not `dplyr`. Use `filter` with identical syntax instead.

Comment: Simplified a bit: `df %>% gather(var, val, -id) %>% separate(var, c('var', 'num')) %>% spread(var, val, convert = TRUE) %>% select(-num) %>% na.omit() %>% spread(artery, diameter)`

Comment: This is great...worked like a charm. Thanks for all your help guys. Love R and the R community!!

Answer (score 2):

Or using `melt`/`dcast` combination with `data.table` while selecting variables using regex in the `patterns` function

```
library(data.table) #v>=1.9.6
dcast(melt(setDT(df), 
           id = "id", 
           measure = patterns("artery", "diameter")),
      id ~ value1, 
      sum, 
      value.var = "value2", 
      subset = .(!is.na(value2)), 
      fill = NA)
#    id  a  b  c  d  e  f
# 1:  1  3  2  3 NA NA NA
# 2:  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA
# 3:  3 NA  1  2  3  4  5
```

As you can see, both `melt` and `dcast` are very flexible and you can use regex, specify a subset, pass multiple functions and specify how you want to fill missing values.

Comment: Yeah, I really wish `tidyr::gather` could do parallel gathering like this. Instead I end up doing terrible things like `df %>% do(bind_cols(gather(., label1, artery, artery.1:artery.5), gather(., label2, diameter, diameter.1:diameter.5) %>% select(-id))) %>% select(id, artery, diameter) %>% na.omit() %>% spread(artery, diameter)`

Comment: @alistaire my main issue with `spread` though, that it has no `fun.aggregate` argument. That really makes in handicapped once not all the combinations unique. Never understood why this functionality was removed really

Comment: Yeah, it's a little finicky about identifiers. I think it's trying to limit itself to just reshaping in order to force people to aggregate only with `summarise` so each function only does one thing so that they're easier to understand and people are less likely to do terrible things with them. Ultimately all reshaping functions (even `table`) drive me a little crazy, each in their unique way.

Comment: @akrun I've used `sum` so the default would be 0. But I guess I could `use `I` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xtabs` with `reshape` from base R. Use the latter to transform data to long format and use the former to get the count table:

```
xtabs(diameter ~ id + artery, reshape(df, varying = 2:11, sep = '.', dir = "long"))

#   artery
#id  a b c d e f
#  1 3 2 3 0 0 0
#  2 2 0 0 0 0 0
#  3 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Really succinct, but this fills missing values with 0 instead of `NA`, doesn't it?

Comment: @jdobres Yes. Not exactly as the desired output but in reality it may still work depending on the need. Besides replacing 0 with `NA` should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with two `reshape()` calls. First, we can longify both `artery` and `diameter` on `id`, then widen with `artery` as the time variable. To prevent a column of NAs, we also must subset out rows with NA values for `artery` in the intermediate frame.

```
reshape(subset(reshape(df,dir='l',varying=setdiff(names(df),'id'),timevar=NULL),!is.na(artery)),dir='w',timevar='artery');
##     id diameter.a diameter.b diameter.c diameter.d diameter.e diameter.f
## 1.1  1          3          2          3         NA         NA         NA
## 2.1  2          2         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
## 3.1  3         NA          1          2          3          4          5
```

The `diameter.` prefixes can be removed afterward, if desired. However, an advantage of this solution is that it would be capable of preserving multiple column sets, whereas the `xtabs()` solution cannot. The prefixes would be essential to distinguish the column sets in that case.